# More than one value for "each" argument in "rep" function?

Tags: r, rep

How to assign more than one value for "each" argument in "rep" function in R? 
A trivial example, where each value in a vector is 3-times repeated in a row:

```
a <- seq(2,6,2)
rep (a,each = 3)
```

However, if I add more than one value in "each" argument in order to change the number of repetition of each value, it doesn't work properly:

```
rep (a, each = c(2,4,7))
```

How to solve it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depending on what you think the output should be, I'm guessing you want the `times=` parameter:

```
rep (a, times = c(2, 4, 7))
# [1] 2 2 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

See `?rep` for the difference